# Possible error in CGAffineTransform documentation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cgaffinetransform

In CGAffineTransform documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform the equations that transform point (x, y) to point (x’,y’) are as follows: x'=ax+cy+t_x, y'=bx+dy+t_y. Consider the case where we have scaling on a view. Then the equations become x'=ax, y'=dy. This means that according to the equations the point that remains at the same position after the scaling is (0,0). However, the point that remains at the same position is the center of the view. This can be seen in practice, as well as here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410817-anchorpoint.

My question is: Are the equations provided in CGAffineTransform documentation, incorrect indeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This means that according to the equations the point that remains at the same position after the scaling is (0,0).

Exactly. But (0,0) is the anchor point, not the "view bounds origin" which I believe you're expecting.

> However, the point that remains at the same position is the center of the view.

Exactly. Because that's where the anchor point is.

You even link to the documentation that explains this. Transforms are applied to a coordinate space based on the anchor point. The default anchor point is in the center of the view. This is independent of the coordinate space of `bounds`.

CALayer works in a coordinate space from (0,0) to (1,1), with (0.5, 0.5) in its center. The default anchor point is the center, but can be moved.

The docs are very clear about that. They're not misleading or incorrect:

> This property [transform] is set to the identity transform by default. Any transformations you apply to the layer occur relative to the layer’s anchor point.

To make the transform "relative to the layer's anchor point," scaling and translation may be applied. That's fine; that's how affine transforms work. They can be freely combined to moved between coordinate spaces. If you want the coordinate space to be anchored a the upper-left corner, move the anchor point.

Comment: Your answer solved my question. However, the CGAffineTransform documentation is indeed misleading. It is not stated that the equations' coordinate system has the anchor point as (0,0)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where you got `This means that according to the equations the point that remains at the same position after the scaling is (0,0).` from.

If you are only SCALING a view, the center point itself does not change, therefore `t_x` and `t_y` does not change, only the scaling at which you see, which is the coefficients `a`x and `d`y change; therefore, WHEN SCALING `x' = ax` and `y' = dy`.

For example, if you scale on an image, let's say your current centerpoint is the CENTER of the image. If you scale, you will scale upon the CENTER of the image. If the user slides the image, that is no longer a ONLY scaling on a view.

Additionally, the point `(0,0)` is NOT the same; the only point that stays the same is the center. Let's say you can see the full image of `(0,0,400,400)` - with the point `(0,0)` at the top left and `(200,200)` at the center. If you zoom in by DOUBLE, you will now have `(100,100)` at the top left and `(200,200)` at the center. Note: `(0,0)` did not stay the same, but the center did.

Answer: No

Comment: The only way to have x'=x and y'=y from x'=ax, y'=dy, is to have x=0, y=0. This is what I meant.

Comment: No, that is incorrect. If `x` and `y` were both 0, then `x' = 0` and `y' = 0`. If you want `x = x'` and `y = y'`, then `a = 1 ` and `d = 1`. Your solution is one way to have `x' = x` and `y' = y`, but it is not the ONLY way

Comment: I mean that the only way to have x'=x and y'=y for every possible a, d, is  x=0, y=0. You are refering just to the special case of a=1, d=1

Answer (score 2):

You are basically equivocating on the terms x and y. The formulae given are the correct linear algebra formulae for what an affine transform is — in the abstract. But nothing is said about how that applies to a particular view.

Actually, the "point that remains at the same position" is arbitrary. You can set it to *any* point of the view. It is the bounds midpoint by default, but you can change that (by changing the anchor point of the view's underlying layer).

So you would simply have to understand that for purposes of the transform, the "origin" is wherever you say it is. By default, it's the bounds midpoint.

To see this more clearly, use the `applying` method of CGPoint, which actually performs the transform for you:

```
let p = CGPoint.zero
let pprime = p.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2))
print(pprime)
```

The result is `.zero`. So, sure enough, whatever point we consider to be the origin for purposes of the transform, does not move as a result of the transform. But there is nothing here about what point *of a particular view* is the origin for purposes for purposes of the transform. Devoid of a context, it is just pure math — and so are the equations you started with.

Comment: I believe that the equtions should be different. Each one should have a costant at the right side, which should be function of the point that does not change position

Comment: `t_x` and `t_y` are the constants - but they will change, accordingly.

Comment: Yes, but if scaling is applied with x'=ax, y'=dy (i.e., with constants as zero), these equations should lead to scaling with the upper left corner as stationary. The equation and the behavior of the view after a transformation, do not match. These equations give the new position of each point of the view. If the upper left corner changes position after the scaling with x'=ax, y'=dy, this means that the actual equations that are applied on the view for the implementation of the scaling, are NOT x'=ax, y'=dy, but different ones

Comment: The only way for these equations to be valid, is to refer to a coordinate system that has (0,0) at the  anchor point of the view's layer (i.e. at center of the view for the default case, or anywhere else the anchor point is placed)